# Delphi 7 - Encrypt with DEC, and decrypt with PHP OpenSSL (Part II)

Tags: php, delphi, base64, delphi-7, php-7.4

Please refer to my earlier question: Delphi 7 - [Encrypt with DEC, and decrypt with PHP OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193109/delphi-7-encrypt-with-dec-and-decrypt-with-php-openssl)

My Delphi 7 client app (ICS components) is sending base64 encoded data as a parameter in a HTTP POST request, to a PHP web service, where it is being decoded with `base64_decode` function. However, the resulting decoded string in PHP is not the same string that was originally encoded in Delphi. The Delphi base64 encoding function that I'm using is from the DEC (DEC v5.2) library.

Sample code implementation for sending data from Delphi to PHP (and receiving a response) is below:

**Delphi side:**

```
uses
  OverbyteIcsHttpProt, OverbyteIcsLogger, OverbyteIcsWSocket, OverbyteIcsSslHttpRest, StrUtils,
  DecFmt;


var
  d: String;
  StatCode: Integer;
  sAPIResponse: WideString;
  APIRespData: TAPIRespData;
begin
  //
  d := 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy rabbit..'; 
  d := Encrypt(d); // Result string A
  d := TFormat_MIME64.Encode(d); // Result string B

  SslHttpRest1.RestParams.Clear;
  SslHttpRest1.RestParams.AddItem('data', d);
  StatCode := SslHttpRest1.RestRequest(httpPOST, strAPIUrl, False, '');
  sAPIResponse := SslHttpRest1.ResponseRaw; // Result string C
```

Encrypt looks like this (Code credit: [@AmigoJack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4299358/amigojack)):

```
const
  GLUE = '::';
  cPASSWORD = 'myownpassword';

function Encrypt(AStr: string): string;
var
  c: TDecCipher; // Successfully tested with DEC 5.2 on Delphi 7
  sKey, // The binary key we have to provide
  sIv, // Initialization vector, should be random in the real world
  sEncrypted, // Output of the encryption
  sPlain: AnsiString; // What we want to encrypt, in binary
  iPlus, // Input data padding
  iLength: Integer; // Plaintext length source, in bytes
begin
  // Keep in mind: Plain, Key and IV are all binary, not text!
  sPlain := AStr;
  sKey := cPASSWORD;

  SetLength(sIv, 16);
  RandomBuffer(sIv[1], 16);

  // The cipher/algorithm depends on fixed block sizes, so it is automatically
  // padded to the next full length. OpenSSL's padding byte is equal to the amount
  // of bytes to be added: if 6 bytes need to be added, then 6 times #6 is added.
  iLength := Length(sPlain);
  iPlus := 16 - (iLength mod 16);
  sPlain := sPlain + StringOfChar(Chr(iPlus), iPlus);

  // Expect DEC 5.2 to only deal with AES-128-CBC, not 256.
  c := ValidCipher(DecCipher.TCipher_Rijndael).Create;
  try
    c.Mode := cmCBCx;
    c.Init(sKey, sIv); // Provide binary key and binary IV
    SetLength(sEncrypted, Length(sPlain)); // Both are multiples of 16
    c.Encode(sPlain[1], sEncrypted[1], Length(sPlain));

    Result := TFormat_MIME64.Encode(sEncrypted) + GLUE + TFormat_MIME64.Encode(sIv) + GLUE + IntToStr(iLength);
  finally
    c.Free;
  end;
end;
```

***Result string A:***

> gS4S0kX9BfrhBYlsZ3MHS9RdgNuuEmKub39aim4/0eiRBPiaw1ykOGOqEk6cY3ol::AAjcM0WrUSlfbBR5EtcPSw==::48

***Result string B:***

> a1FUTWtyVFlNVWc1UlREL2lEOXVPaTZUcmtDaHRiMUFLWU9DRVRxODUvQVNpZkJzMEs2Y2xxMU50VGZCNjdOYzo6Nmw3R1U3TFl0MDRwVkhjLzAwZDdKZz09Ojo0OA==

***Result string C:***

> B:a1FUTWtyVFlNVWc1UlREL2lEOXVPaTZUcmtDaHRiMUFLWU9DRVRxODUvQVNpZkJzMEs2Y2xxMU50VGZCNjdOYzo6Nmw3R1U3TFl0MDRwVkhjLzAwZDdKZz09Ojo0OA== A:kQTMkrTYMUg5RTD/iD9uOi6TrkChtb1AKYOCETq85/ASifBs0K6clq1NtTfB67Nc::6l7GU7LYt04pVHc/00d7Jg==::48

**PHP side:**

```
$data=$_POST['data'];          echo 'B:' . $data;
$data=base64_decode($data);    echo ' A:' . $data;
```

I am expecting `String A` to be equal to the string returned in `String C (label A:)`, but they aren't.

Imho, the bug relates to either something missing relating to character set encoding, or, an incompatibility between DEC's `TFormat_MIME64.Encode` function and PHP (PHP v7.4.7) `base64_decode` function.

Any help in resolving this or pointing me in the right direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be true - "Result string B" cannot become what you stated. Are you sure you use [DEC5.2](https://github.com/decfpc/DelphiEncryptionCompendium/blob/master/Ver.inc) and not an older version?

```
var
  sAll, sAgain: AnsiString;
begin
  sAll:= 'gS4S0kX9BfrhBYlsZ3MHS9RdgNuuEmKub39aim4/0eiRBPiaw1ykOGOqEk6cY3ol::AAjcM0WrUSlfbBR5EtcPSw==::48';
  sAgain:= TFormat_MIME64.Encode( sAll );
  if sAgain<> 'Z1M0UzBrWDlCZnJoQllsc1ozTUhTOVJkZ051dUVtS3ViMzlhaW00LzBlaVJCUGlhdzF5a09HT3FFazZjWTNvbDo6QUFqY00wV3JVU2xmYkJSNUV0Y1BTdz09Ojo0OA==' then Halt;
```

Also it is totally pointless to encode your ASCII string **again** in Base64 - you just inflate it even more without any benefit.

Comment: The above code works fine without error, and, yes I am using DEC v5.2 downloaded from the repository.

Comment: And now? You've proved yourself that either your "Result string A" or "Result string B" must be something different from what you stated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I removed the extra process of encoding the encrypted string again (and decoding it in PHP) and now it works perfectly fine! It seems that there is an issue with applying the MIME encoding an already encoded string.